# "statt dass" is not good German?

Tags: grammar, conjunction

I saw this sentence in a DaF grammar exercise book:

> ***Statt dass*** wir hier lange Erklärungen geben, sollten wir lieber mit den Übungen anfangen.

I found the structure very interesting, so I googled it. And I found a discussion on one of the language forums where a couple of people expressed their opinion and said that "statt dass" doesn't sound very good in German.

They recommend rephrasing it into "statt ... zu..." structure. So I guess it would be something like: "Statt hier lange Erklärungen zu geben..."

Is that true? Then why would they include it in a textbook for someone who learns German as a second language?

Comment: Sounds bad style to me too... textbooks are not always the greatest. Maybe just take it as an example that they are not perfect

Comment: But this sentence is from a Hueber textbook _Großes Übungsbuch Grammatik_. This company publishes a lot of books about languages. So strange that they don't pay attention to bad style.

Comment: I think it is grammatically correct but I'd never write it that way. I might say though.

Comment: It is more recent usage. While it is still considered bad style, it nonetheless is correct. I recommend using the sentence using "... zu ...". If you are still learning German, it is helpful to first learn the "good style" and only later let it slip a little. That way, you can better understand the underlying rules.

Comment: the "statt ... zu..." structure is veeerrry correct and sounds good or "anstelle, dass wir hier lange warten, sollten wir..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using "Statt dass" would be quite the same as using "'stead of" in English. It wouldn't be wrong, but it would also be a bit sloppy. I would recommend "**Anstatt** lange Erklärungen zu geben, sollten wir lieber mit den Übungen anfangen." which would mean "instead of giving long explanations…".

Or, an alternative that would also be nice: "**Anstelle** langer Erklärungen" ["**In place of** long explanations [where the meaning of "long" would be in the direction of exhausting]  …"

Comment: Depending on the word order **stattdessen** may also be a good choice.

Comment: Aber wieso sollte denn "Anstatt, dass" falsch sein?

Comment: @Dan, es ist nicht falsch. Nur klingen die alternativen Varianten oft besser.